# Extract a MATLAB function from text

Tags: javascript, regex

I's trying to extract a MATLAB function from a text file uploaded. For instance,

```
% A
function [sol] = A(a, P)
sol = (a * P) ;
end

%! B
function [sol] = B(b, P)
sol = (b * P);
end

and more ...
```

I defined a regex as:

```
const mFileFunctionRegex = /function\s*\[?([a-zA-Z0-9_,/\s]+)\]?\s*=\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_]*(?=\())\s*\(([a-zA-Z0-9_,\s]+)\)\s*((.*\n*(?!\s*end))*)/gm;
```

It worked but if the function is defined as

```
%! C
function [sol] = C(b, P)
   for c = 1:s
      %some code
   end
sol = (c * P);
end
```

Then, it results in:

```
 function [sol] = C(b, P)
       for c = 1:s
          %some code
```

is there any way to take only the last "end".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your functions are all indented nicely then the last end will be the one with no indent on the line.

```js
const regex = /^function(.*?)^end$/gms;
```

This matches a line starting with `function` and no indent and then all characters up until a line containing only `end` with no indent

```js
const functions = `
% A
function [sol] = A(a, P)
sol = (a * P) ;
end

%! B
function [sol] = B(b, P)
sol = (b * P);
end

and more ...

%! C
function [sol] = C(b, P)
   for c = 1:s
      %some code
   end
sol = (c * P);
end
`;

const regex = /^function(.*?)^end$/gms;
console.log(functions.match(regex));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ;) however, s flag is not supported by all browsers,

Comment: Oh good point, I think if you remove the s flag you can just change this `(.*?)` to `((.|[\r\n])*?)`

Comment: as you said "the codes should be indented correctly" otherwise it just finds the first "end"
`function [sol] = C(b, P)
for c = 1:s
      %some code
end
sol = (c * P);
end`

not working, even I tried to add (?!end).

I am not sure, the alternative is to split the code based on the regex (function ~) then find the lastIndexOf (end), finally remove the rest of end, what would you think